# Read Array of NSDictionaries With String Interpolation in Swift

Tags: swift, nsdictionary

This freaks out because it finds an unexpected " in the string interpolation:

```
let temp = "\(catalogueRows[0]["person"])"
```

Tried using single quotes but that didn't work. Seems like a pretty simple step and I'm confused why it doesn't work.

Comment: It doesn't "freak out". _You_ "freak out", perhaps. But you shouldn't. If you can't accept that computer languages have syntax rules, don't program.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use quotes in a string interpolation. That's just the way the syntax is.

You can't "escape" or single-quote your way out. You'll need two lines of code to do what you're trying to do:

```
let temptemp = catalogueRows[0]["person"]
let temp = "\(temptemp)"
```